Jenkins Pipeline as YAML
I am writing a pipeline with YAML format. I came across a requirement where I need to use copy artifact plugin in a pipeline.
I am unable to find the correct way of doing this as; getting error
Error when running task: hudson.AbortException: Unable to find project for artifact copy: <ProjectName> This may be due to incorrect project name or permission settings; see help for project name in job configuration.
I am able to do this if I use pipeline script the code looks like this in YAML :
  properties:
    copyArtifactPermission: '<Path of project we need to copy from along with branch name>'
tasks:
- name: Copy Artifact
  type: run
  groovy: |
   copyArtifacts(projectName: '<Path of project we need to copy from along with branch name>', filter: '<folder name>', optional: true)

I tried with giving permission to the path of the project as well using copy artifact permission property.
Need help with syntax how to be able to use this in YAML format of Jenkins pipeline. Thanks

YAML? What plugin is that?

Similar to this: https://cd.foundation/blog/2020/08/18/pipeline-as-yaml/

What’s ’tasks:’? I don’t see it in the documentation of the plug-in you mentioned https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-as-yaml/
